# Transition between 3 different classes

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like my website to transition between showing the three different sets of text below but I don't know where to start. The idea is it will initially say:
Your
Charity
365 Partner

then it will swap to:
Your
Education
365 Partner

If anyone could help guide me in the right direction, thank you.

```
 <section>
        <div class="containerBody">
            <div class="BodyImages"> 
        <div class="banner-top-mob d-lg-none"><img src="/images/BannerImage1.jpg" class="img-fluid"></div>
            <div class="banner-bottom-mob d-lg-none"><img src="/images/BannerImage2.jpg" class="img-fluid"></div>
        </div>
            <div class="tes-banner__slider p-4 mt-4 mt-md-0 pb-xl-8">
                                    <div class="tes-banner__content p-1">
                        <h2 class="mb-3">
                            Your<br>
                            <span class="banner-title">Charity</span><br>
                            365 Partner
                        </h2>
                        <p>We've been implementing Microsoft Dynamics 365 into not-for-profit organisations and the public sector for decades. As a result, our team of experts really do understand the complexities and challenges that you face as a sector.</p>
                        <a href="/charity" class="btn btn-outline-blue mt-3">Discover</a>
                    </div>
                                    <div class="tes-banner__content p-1">
                        <h2 class="mb-3">
                            Your<br>
                            <span class="banner-title">Education</span><br>
                            365 Partner
                        </h2>
                        <p>Schools and academies are small businesses, which need robust financial systems. We offer you the ideal solution to manage the end-to-end operations of your school or academy.</p>
                        <a href="/education" class="btn btn-outline-blue mt-3">Find out more</a>
                    </div>
                                    <div class="tes-banner__content p-1">
                        <h2 class="mb-3">
                            Your<br>
                            <span class="banner-title">Commercial</span><br>
                            365 Partner
                        </h2>
                        <p>Whatever your industry sector, the pace of business is constantly changing. Dynamics 365 allows you to streamline your processes, make smarter decisions and accelerate business growth, all the while connecting all key parts of your organisation.</p>
                        <a href="/contact" class="btn btn-outline-blue mt-3">Get in touch</a>
                    </div>
                                    
        </div>
    </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: Yep. Research how to position elements on top of each other. Then use a CSS opacity transition to fade between them.

Comment: I have seen I can use animation and KeyFrames to set the opacity thank you. 
However if I set the animation to disappear how do I keep it off the page for longer than a second or swap between the two images?

@keyframes Image1 {
    from {opacity: 100%}
    to {opacity: 0%}

Answer (score 0):

You need to add JavaScrip to make it work. Using the `setInterval`, you can make the function run every couple seconds.

```js
var sections = [
  document.getElementById("section1"),
  document.getElementById("section2"),
  document.getElementById("section3")
]
var on = 0

setInterval(function() {
  sections[on].style.display = "none"
  on += 1
  if (on == sections.length) {
    on = 0
  }
  sections[on].style.display = "block"
}, 1000) // The number is the time (in milliseconds) for each flip
```

```css
#seciont1 {
  display: block;
}

#section2,
#section3 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="containerBody">
    <div class="BodyImages">
      <div class="banner-top-mob d-lg-none"><img src="/images/BannerImage1.jpg" class="img-fluid"></div>
      <div class="banner-bottom-mob d-lg-none"><img src="/images/BannerImage2.jpg" class="img-fluid"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="tes-banner__slider p-4 mt-4 mt-md-0 pb-xl-8">
      <div class="tes-banner__content p-1" id="section1">
        <h2 class="mb-3">
          Your<br>
          <span class="banner-title">Charity</span><br> 365 Partner
        </h2>
        <p>We've been implementing Microsoft Dynamics 365 into not-for-profit organisations and the public sector for decades. As a result, our team of experts really do understand the complexities and challenges that you face as a sector.</p>
        <a href="/charity" class="btn btn-outline-blue mt-3">Discover</a>
      </div>
      <div class="tes-banner__content p-1" id="section2">
        <h2 class="mb-3">
          Your<br>
          <span class="banner-title">Education</span><br> 365 Partner
        </h2>
        <p>Schools and academies are small businesses, which need robust financial systems. We offer you the ideal solution to manage the end-to-end operations of your school or academy.</p>
        <a href="/education" class="btn btn-outline-blue mt-3">Find out more</a>
      </div>
      <div class="tes-banner__content p-1" id="section3">
        <h2 class="mb-3">
          Your<br>
          <span class="banner-title">Commercial</span><br> 365 Partner
        </h2>
        <p>Whatever your industry sector, the pace of business is constantly changing. Dynamics 365 allows you to streamline your processes, make smarter decisions and accelerate business growth, all the while connecting all key parts of your organisation.</p>
        <a href="/contact" class="btn btn-outline-blue mt-3">Get in touch</a>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Change the `1000` to change the amount of time between each flip. It is in milliseconds, so 1000 is equal to 1 second.